# how autorun works in linux

Tags: linux

i came to know that selfinvoking functions are there in linux  based systems
is it really possible  ! using C program 
how can i impliment this in a C program
is there any function in C
can anybody help me  , does autorun works in linux   and  how ?

please  brainstorm me

Answer (score 1):

[Autostart specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html)

[D-Bus activation](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/IntroductionToDBus#line-133)